# Why am I getting IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed. in sending Email?

Tags: .net

I have this code.

```
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            using var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("hr@menacom-amman.com"));
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Test";
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string pdfFilePath = "C:\\Users\\m_243\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\microsoft documentation\\.net core\\SendEmailTest" +
                "\\SendEmailTest\\wwwroot\\MohammadJouhariCV.pdf";
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
            using var attachment = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "MohammadJouhariCV.");
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
           
            NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("mohammad.jouhari@gmail.com", "password"); // password for connection smtp if u dont have have then pass blank
            _smtpClient.EnableSsl= true;
            _smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            _smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
            _smtpClient.Send(mailMessage); // _smtpClient will be disposed by
```

I have alsp

```
builder.Services.Configure<SmtpOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Smtp"));
// SmtpClient is not thread-safe, hence transient
builder.Services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    var smtpOptions = provider.GetService<IOptions<SmtpOptions>>().Value;
    return new SmtpClient(smtpOptions.Host, smtpOptions.Port)
    {
        // Credentials and EnableSsl here when required
        
    };
});
```

Here is my SmtpOptions

```
public class SmtpOptions
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Any reason, I am getting the error ?

Comment: https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/06/how-to-send-email-using-gmail.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using _smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;  and using app password from goofle.

Firstly, make sure that your two-step verification is on. Now, go to the "Manage your Google Account", then click the "Security" tab.

https://www.techaeblogs.live/2022/06/how-to-send-email-using-gmail.html